# Double precision floating point operations using Arduino

Tags: arduino-nano, c

Today we were programming something in university which dealt with really large numbers (even larger than unsigned long) and we had to create a code that broke the  numbers into an array and performed operations on them.

I know that an Arduino is an 8 bit MCU, but I was wondering if similar approaches could be used to do 32 bit double precision floating point operations (or even better,  i.e quad precision, etc) using the Arduino (e.g. create a quad precision calculator or similar applications).

I know it sounds silly or similar to a brute force method, but I'm really curious if it's possible to do such things.

Comment: Anything is possible if you have the programming skills. Natively the highest precision Arduino supports is `float`. Anything more precise you will have to code your own support for from scratch. Or there's Nick Gammon's [Big Number library](https://github.com/nickgammon/BigNumber) for massive integer use.

Comment: Note also that double precision is actually 64 bits (with 52+1 bits in the mantissa). For integers, avr-gcc natively supports `int64_t` and `uint64_t`.

Comment: The source code for float handling in AVR could be a starting point. The compiler back-end for AVR might need changing so that true double literal numbers could be used in sketches. https://github.com/vancegroup-mirrors/avr-libc/tree/master/avr-libc/libm/fplib

Comment: Thanks everyone. I'm a bit busy but I'll try to come up with some sort of code myself. I'll ask more details if I couldn't figure something on my own, thanks.